# Joda DateTime array sort array by date time

Tags: sorting, datetime, arraylist, jodatime, comparator

I have an arraylist of Joda DateTimes like this:

```
List <DateTime> nextRemindersArray = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
nextRemindersArray.add(reminderOneDateTime);
nextRemindersArray.add(reminderTwoDateTime);
nextRemindersArray.add(reminderThreeDateTime);
```

I am trying to sort the dates in ascending order but I am having trouble:

I googled it and found this page:

https://cmsoftwaretech.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/sort-date-with-timezone-format-using-joda-time/

I tried it like this:

```
nextRemindersArray.sort(nextRemindersArray);
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Error:(1496, 37) error: incompatible types: List<DateTime> cannot be converted to Comparator<? super DateTime>
```

I then tried like this:

```
DateTimeComparator dateTimeComparator = DateTimeComparator.getInstance();
nextRemindersArray.sort(nextRemindersArray, dateTimeComparator);
```

and also like this:

```
nextRemindersArray.sort(nextRemindersArray, new DateTimeComparator());
```

but all have errors.

I tried the Joda time manual and that wasn't much help. How do I sort the array?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
nextRemindersArray.sort(DateTimeComparator.getInstance());
```

But because `DateTime` already implements `Comparable`, you don't really need a comparator and you can simply use:

```
nextRemindersArray.sort(null); //uses natural sorting
//or probably more readable
Collections.sort(nextRemindersArray);
```

Note that a quick look at [the documentation of `List::sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) would have shown you that the method expects only one argument and it has to be a Comparator (and not two arguments like in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have SomeClass with this method getCreatedDate() which returns a DateTime joda object.
For a List you can have a simple comparator:

```
private Comparator<Listing> byCreatedDate = Comparator.comparing(SomeClass::getCreatedDate);
```

Then in your code you can call:

```
 ...
 listings.sort(byCreatedDate);
 return listings;
 ...
```

Haven't tested it but ... the idea should be ok.

In Kotlin you would call listing.sortedBy { it.createdDate }